# .NET Using expression tree to to see if list is in another list

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, rules

I am working on a rules engine.  Because of the nature of our business rules, one possible solution is to use expression to dynamically calling methods based on the rules.  Since I am new to expression, I am not sure how to do the following:

```
public class Order
    {
        public Order()
        {
            this.Items = new List<Item>();
        }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
    }
    public class Country
    {
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is what I have populated the Order object with:

```
public Order GetOrder()
        {
            Order order = new Order()
            {
                OrderId = 1,
                Customer = new Customer()
                {
                    FirstName = "John",
                    LastName = "Doe",
                    Country = new Country()
                    {
                        CountryCode = "AUS"
                    }
                },
                Items = new List<Item>(){
                    new Item(){ ItemCode = "MM23", Cost=5.25M, Status=1},
                    new Item(){ ItemCode = "LD45", Cost=5.25M, Status=0},
                    new Item(){ ItemCode = "Test", Cost=3.33M, Status=1},
                }
            };
            return order;
        }
```

One of my rules is to check if the order has itemcode in ("MM23", "LD45") and the status is not 1.

```
 GetOrder().Items.Where(x => list.Contains(x.ItemCode) && x.Status !=1).Any();
```

Comment: Did you run your code? and what problem you got?

Comment: Not sure about an absolute answer, but I would suggest flipping your check around and check `x.Status != 1` first; no sense iterating through with `list.Contains` just to throw out the result because `x.Status == 1`.

Comment: What is `list` in `list.Contains`?

Comment: The above code works.  That's just one of the many rules, I need to build that in expression and i am not sure how to do that.

Comment: List<string> list = new List<string>() { "LD45", "MM23" };